# Invalidate control on Save

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF form that has some controls. One of the controls is a text box that specifies an string property[image]

defined by:

```
        <TextBox>
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="ExtractName" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <ExceptionValidationRule />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

The binded property is defined as:

```
    private string _extractName;
    public string ExtractName
    {
        get { return _extractName; }
        set
        {
            var extract_id = (int?) null;
            if(SelectedExtract != null)
            {
                extract_id = SelectedExtract.ExtractId;
            }

            if(SelectedExtract == null)
            if (WebServiceCall.ExtractNameExists(extract_id, value))
            {
                _isExtractNameValid = false;
                throw new ApplicationException("Extract Name already exists");
            }

            if (value == "")
            {
                _isExtractNameValid = false;
                throw new ApplicationException("Extract Name cannot be empty");
            }

            _extractName = value;
            _isExtractNameValid = true;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ExtractName");
        }
    }
```

This works just fine if the user enters the control and writes something in it.

[image]

But, when a call to the save method is made,  I  want the control to check all validations and if something is wrong, the text box should be colored red.

How can I do this from the view model?

Comment: Placing your validation in the UI is not a great idea because of situations like this.  Validating models is a business concern.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement `IDataErrorInfo` providing a collection of validation results. That would be easier to check before/while save.

You could also do a very dirty solution: Set all properties with their current value when calling save, this will re-validate them with your current method. You could also store the validation errors and re-validate only these properties (at least a bit cleaner)

A very simplified version of the approach would be:

```
this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList()
    .ForEach(prop => prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(this, null), null));
```

[Example for `IDataErrorInfo`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo)

Comment: Setting the value to the existing value should be done from code behind not from view model. Right?

Comment: Note that when you use IDataErrorInfo (or INotifyDataErrorInfo, which is my preference) your View may not update its validation state if errors change outside of the setter for a particular property.  For example, if you're using cross-property validation rules then a change to property A might invalidate property B.  In order to force the view to update the validation state for B you'll need to raise the PropertyChanged event for B.

Comment: @Corovei Andrei no you could use reflection in the view model to get all properties (maybe mark them with an attribute) and set them through their `PropertyInfo`s

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IDataErrorInfo` on entity & at saving time do following logic for checking error existence.

```
 foreach (var item in DataContext.GetChangeSet().Inserts)
 {
    IDataErrorInfo errofInfo = item as IDataErrorInfo;
     if(errofInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errofInfo.Error))
     {
         //// Error Exist;
     }
 }

 foreach (var item in DataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates)
 {
    IDataErrorInfo errofInfo = item as IDataErrorInfo;
     if(errofInfo != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errofInfo.Error))
     {
         //// Error Exist;
     }
 }
```

This will improve error checking performance also.